# getDeclaredField returns nosuchfield exception even the field exists

Tags: java

I'm using Truffle&Graal projects in my own projects. I come across a problem that when I use `getDeclaredField()` in Java, it returns noSuchFieldException even the field exists.

The code producing exception is

```
Field field = NodeUtil.class.getDeclaredField("unsafeFieldOffsetProvider");
field.setAccessible(true);
```

And the field `unsafeFieldOffsetProvider` is declared in NodeUtil.java

```
private static final FieldOffsetProvider unsafeFieldOffsetProvider = new FieldOffsetProvider() {

    @Override
    public long objectFieldOffset(Field field) {
        return unsafe.objectFieldOffset(field);
    }

    @Override
    public int getTypeSize(Class<?> clazz) {
        if (!clazz.isPrimitive()) {
            return Unsafe.ARRAY_OBJECT_INDEX_SCALE;
        } else if (clazz == int.class) {
            return Unsafe.ARRAY_INT_INDEX_SCALE;
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unsupported field type: " + clazz);
        }
    }
};
```

Here are the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at edu.uci.python.runtime.object.FixedObjectLayout.<init>(FixedObjectLayout.java:100)
at edu.uci.python.runtime.object.FixedObjectLayout.addAttribute(FixedObjectLayout.java:149)
at edu.uci.python.runtime.object.PythonObject.setAttribute(PythonObject.java:153)
at edu.uci.python.runtime.standardtype.PythonModule.addDefaultConstants(PythonModule.java:45)
at edu.uci.python.runtime.standardtype.PythonModule.<init>(PythonModule.java:41)
at edu.uci.python.builtins.PythonDefaultBuiltinsLookup.createModule(PythonDefaultBuiltinsLookup.java:88)
at edu.uci.python.builtins.PythonDefaultBuiltinsLookup.populateBuiltins(PythonDefaultBuiltinsLookup.java:54)
at edu.uci.python.runtime.PythonContext.<init>(PythonContext.java:79)
at python.truffle.toa.runtime.PythonContextOA.<init>(PythonContextOA.java:13)
at python.truffle.toa.main.PythonMainOA.testFile(PythonMainOA.java:78)
at python.truffle.toa.main.PythonMainOA.main(PythonMainOA.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException:    unsafeFieldOffsetProvider
at edu.uci.python.runtime.object.ObjectLayoutUtil.unsafeFieldOffsetProvider(ObjectLayoutUtil.java:43)
at edu.uci.python.runtime.object.ObjectLayoutUtil.<clinit>(ObjectLayoutUtil.java:47)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: unsafeFieldOffsetProvider
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Unknown Source)
at edu.uci.python.runtime.object.ObjectLayoutUtil.unsafeFieldOffsetProvider(ObjectLayoutUtil.java:39)
... 12 more
```

Comment: If the field really is declared in the class you're referencing, that won't happen. [Example.](http://ideone.com/uOOini) So clearly it must not really be in that class; perhaps the source and the `.class` file are not in sync? Perhaps you're referencing a *different* `NodeUtil` class?

Comment: Yes, that's the point. I'll double check the build path and project resource.

Comment: I don't know this Truffle&Graal project very well. But could it be that it creates Proxy objects for your Nodes ?

Comment: Declaring a member `private` implies: “Don’t rely on its existence. Don’t think about it at all”

Answer (score 0):

The field doesn't exist in the Truffle version you are using.

v0.6 - field [unsafeFieldOffsetProvider](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.oracle/truffle/0.6/com/oracle/truffle/api/nodes/NodeUtil.java/#58) exist in `NodeUtil.java`

v0.7 - field [unsafeFieldOffsetProvider](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.oracle/truffle/0.7/com/oracle/truffle/api/nodes/NodeUtil.java/) doesn't exist in `NodeUtil.java`

Comment: But the `unsafeFieldOffsetProvider` is already declared in NodeUtil.java as I stated in the question.

Comment: And which Truffle version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually we figured out (I'm on the same project as @lhan) that it was caused by the wrong order of the dependencies of our Eclipse project configuration... We had to change the order of dependencies in the tab "Order and Export" in the "Java Build Path" setting of the project. Specifically, we had to put `com.oracle.truffle.api` and `com.oracle.truffle.api.dsl` above JRE System Library.